# Proof of the Deduction Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's the result I'm trying to prove:

Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas in $L_p$ and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any formulas. Then, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$ iff $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$. Then, there is a deduction $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n$ is $\alpha \to \beta$. Now, consider $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\}$. Construct a deduction $\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_{n+2}$ as follows:

1. $\psi_i$ is $\phi_i$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
2. $\psi_{n+1}$ is $\alpha$.
3. $\psi_{n+2}$ is inferred from $\psi_{n+1}$ and $\psi_n$ by Modus Ponens

Since $\psi_n$ is just $\alpha \to \beta$, it follows that $\psi_{n+2}$ is $\beta$. Hence, there is a deduction from $\Sigma \cup \{a\}$ to $\beta$ so $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta$.

Now, suppose that $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta$. Suppose that there is no deduction from $\Sigma$ to $\alpha \to \beta$. Then, there are a few claims we can make (and prove). For this, we will make use of the Axiom Schema:

$$(\beta \to (\alpha \to \beta))$$

1. $\alpha \notin \Sigma$. Otherwise, $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} = \Sigma \vdash \beta$. So, by the Axiom Schema above and by Modus Ponens, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$.
2. $\beta \notin \Sigma$. Otherwise, $\Sigma \vdash \beta$ and so, by the Axiom Schema above and by Modus Ponens, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$
3. $\Sigma$ does not syntactically entail $\beta$. Otherwise, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$ by the Axiom Schema above anad by Modus Ponens.
4. $\Sigma$ does not syntactically entail $\alpha$. Otherwise, all instances of $\alpha$ in the deduction of $\beta$ from $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\}$ can be replaced by the deduction of $\alpha$ from $\Sigma$. Hence, $\Sigma \vdash \beta$ and that is not possible.

Now, since $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta$, there exists a deduction $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n$ is $\beta$. Take the deduction which has minimum length. This exists by the Well-Ordering Principle.

It is obvious that $\alpha$ has to appear amongst the formulas $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-1}$ at least once. In fact, because $\alpha \in \Sigma \cup \{\alpha\}$, we can say that it only appears once and we can assign it to $\phi_{n-1}$. But that means that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2}$ has to yield $\alpha \to \beta$. Otherwise, more steps will be required to deduce $\beta$ and this cannot be possible since this is the deduction of minimum length.

However, the deduction $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2}$ can be constructed with $\Sigma$ because it will consist only of instances of the axiom schemas or formulas from $\Sigma$ or inferences via Modus Ponens. Hence, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$. Since this is impossible, it follows that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ is not a deduction of $\beta$ from $\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\}$. This is a contradiction. Hence, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

**Edit**

I just want to clarify that here's the deductive system that I'm using. I'm using the following three axiom schema:

1. $(\alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha))$
2. $((\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma)))$
3. $((\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to ((\lnot \beta \to \alpha) \to \beta)$

In addition to these three axiom schema, I'm using Modus Ponens as my rule of inference. So, if I have a formula $\psi$ and a formula $(\psi \to \phi)$, then I can infer $\phi$.

Comment: Bump would still not be opposed to some feedback about this

Comment: Your proof seems basically correct, but it could be briefed. Also, I'm not sure we can assume that exactly $\phi_{n-1}$ is the $\alpha$: consequences of $\alpha$ (and previous steps) may appear in internal steps in order to prove $\beta$.

Comment: Well, the idea is that this is the shortest possible deduction of $\beta$ so once we have $\alpha$, then all we need is $\alpha \to \beta$ to prove $\beta$. But that bugs me slightly. Do you have any suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: I think we can simply transform any deduction of $\beta$ to one of $\alpha\to\beta$: whenever $\alpha$ appears in the proof (btw either as hypothesis or as consequence), we can do *something*.. though I'm not certain exactly what, but you seem to work more comfortably with your deduction rules and axiom schemas.. I think after that something, every formula in the deduction can receive the prefix $\alpha\to$, so that the last formula will indeed be $\alpha\to\beta$.

Comment: Erh I'm not quite sure I follow exactly what you're saying. Would you mind explicitly writing what you're thinking about? I'll try to think through everything you've said in the meantime (sorry haha)

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure either, that's why I don't write an answer. What deduction rule do you have to produce an implication?

Comment: So, I'm using the following three axiom schema:

1. $(\alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha))$


2. $((\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma)))$



3. $((\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to ((\lnot \beta \to \alpha) \to \beta)$

In addition to these three axiom schema, I'm using Modus Ponens as my rule of inference. (I will edit this into my post as well, in case this comment is not readable)

Comment: Also, I really am very sorry if I've been unclear at all in what I'm writing. I'm trying to get better but it is difficult.

Comment: I suggest to consider some specific examples. E.g. how do you prove $A\land B\to A$?