# An Inconsistent Set of Formulas Syntactically Entails Anything

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $\Delta$ be an inconsistent set of formulas. Then, for any formula $\psi$, $\Delta \vdash \psi$.

---

Proof Attempt:

We have previously shown that $\{(\alpha \land \beta) \} \vdash \alpha$. Let $\psi$ be any formula. Since $\Delta$ is inconsistent, it follows that:

$$\Delta \vdash (\lnot(\psi \to \psi))$$

However, $(\lnot(\psi \to \psi))$ is just $(\psi \land (\lnot \psi))$. Then, there is a deduction from $(\psi \land (\lnot \psi))$ to $\psi$. Hence, there is a deduction from $\Delta$ to $\psi$ and that is what we wanted to show. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Would there be any alternative argument that doesn't actually rely on the fact that I proved previously?

Comment: Does the argument above work? It depends... what is the precise def of *inconsistent*? $\Gamma \vdash \bot$ ? $\Gamma \vdash (\alpha \land \lnot \alpha)$ ?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Yes, the latter is the precise definition of inconsistent. So, a set of formulas $\Delta$ is inconsistent if $\Delta \vdash \lnot(\alpha \to \alpha)$ for any formula $\alpha$.

Comment: So the proof does work then, I assume?

Comment: As you said, the proof is about derivability: $\vdash$. Thus, it works provided that you have proved the results about $\vdash$ to be used . What is necessary is that you can derive $\psi$ from the "inconsistent formula". If the incons formula is $\psi \land \lnot \psi$, the result needs (as you say) $\alpha \land \beta \vdash \alpha$. If the incons formula is $\lnot (\psi \to \psi)$ you need $\lnot (\alpha \to \alpha) \vdash \alpha$. In conclusion, your proof works provided that you have proved $\lnot (\alpha \to \alpha)  \vdash (\alpha \land \lnot \alpha)$.

Comment: Oh okay, so in my text, it's sort of just been stated that $\alpha \land \beta$ is an abbreviation for $\lnot(\alpha \to \lnot \beta)$. Hmm but now that I'm thinking about it, using the fact that $\lnot(\alpha \to \alpha)$ is $\alpha \land \lnot \alpha$ relies on the fact that $\lnot(\lnot \beta)$ is $\beta$ and I'm not entirely sure that that's justified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume as axioms those of [the linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897753/proof-of-the-deduction-theorem) proof system.

With Ax.1 and Ax.2 we can prove (many copy of the proof on this site): $\vdash (\alpha \to \alpha)$.

Using the following instance of Ax.1:

> $(\psi \to \psi) \to (\lnot \psi \to (\psi \to \psi))$.

and the previous result we have:

> $\text { (1)   } \vdash (\lnot \psi \to (\psi \to \psi))$.

Using the following instance of Ax.1:

> $\lnot (\psi \to \psi) \to (\lnot \psi \to \lnot (\psi \to \psi))$

we have:

> $\text { (2)   } \lnot (\psi \to \psi) \vdash (\lnot \psi \to \lnot (\psi \to \psi))$.

Using the following instance of Ax.3:

> $[(\lnot \psi \to \lnot (\psi \to \psi)) \to ((\lnot \psi \to (\psi \to \psi)) \to \psi)]$

we have, form (1) and (2) by MP:

> $\text { (3)   } \lnot (\psi \to \psi) \vdash \psi$.

---

Thus, if $\text {Incons}(\Delta)$ is defined as: $\Delta \vdash ¬(α → α)$ for any formula $α$, using (3) above we have:

> > if $Δ$ is an inconsistent set of formulas, then $Δ \vdash ψ$, for any formula $\psi$.

Comment: Apologies again for the delayed response (was busy with uni-related stuff). Thank you so much for the proof, I'll study this in greater depth on my own and ask questions if I have any.

Comment: @Abhi - you are welcome :-)